# How can I append elements inputted by user in a tk.Entry object into a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a very simple program in Python and Tkinter that allows the user to input people's names by keyboard and then a button is commanded to select a person from the list at random and show it in a `tk.Label` object.

My problem is once I run the `root.mainloop()`, I can add names to the list but the list does not update with the new names.

**This is the main code for the Tkinter to initialize**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Millor persona del moment')
root.geometry("500x200")
root.configure(bg='black')

peopleList = []

tk.Label(root, text="Insertar participante: ",fg="#ff007f", bg='black').grid(row=0)
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
addButton = tk.Button(root, text='Añadir', padx=10, pady=5, fg="#ff007f", bg='black', command=addPerson)
addButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

while peopleList:
    turnButton = tk.Button(root, text='Saca Tema', padx=10, pady=5, fg="#ff007f", bg='black', command=wordTurn(peopleList))
    turnButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

nom = tk.StringVar()
nom.set('Comencem')

personSpeaking = tk.Label(root, textvariable=nom,fg="#ff007f", bg='black')
personSpeaking.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

**And these are the functions I use**

```
def addPerson():
    peopleList.append(e1.get())
    e1.delete(0,'end')
    
def wordTurn(peopleList):
    person = random.choice(peopleList)
    peopleList.remove(person)        
    nom.set(person)
```

Comment: `command=wordTurn(peopleList)` this will call the function immediately. Don't pass `peopleList` to `wordTurn`... let is access the global `peopleList` as you are doing in `addPerson`. When you are doing `command=wordTurn(peopleList)` it is calling the function once (because of the `()`).

Comment: To elaborate on @Yatin, by putting brackets after the function name in `command=wordTurn(peopleList)` you are **running** the function, and then the return result of that function is being used as the argument for `command`. You could use a lambda function, such as `lambda : wordTurn(peopleList)`

Comment: I don't understand the point of `while peopleList: ...` -  you've initialized `peopleList` as an empty list, so that block of code will never run. Are you expecting that code to run sometime after the user has clicked some buttons or entered data? Also, `command=wordTurn(peopleList)` _immediate_ runs `wordTurn(peoleList)` before the button is created. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I was using while peopleList to prevent the button line from running while the list was empty. I was not aware of the fact that command in the button object was already calling the function and that was causing the error. Thanks a lot for your answers, this should make the program work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

`command=wordTurn(peopleList))` calls the return value of wordTurn when the button is pressed, which is None and should raise an error. Use `command=lambda peopleList=peopleList: wordTurn(peopleList))` instead.